# Fetching data using asynchronous function call in javascript does not work (doesn't follow the execution sequence)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to build a React project where I have a component that fetches data from a remote server and plots it.

```js
async function fetchRemoteData(name) {
  let dataItem = null;
  if (name) {
    await fetch("/endpoint/" + name)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((payload) => {
        console.log("payload = " + JSON.stringify(payload));
        dataItem = payload;
      });
  } else {
    console.log("Error: No data for " + name);
  }
  return dataItem;
}

var RenderPlot = ({ match }) => {
    let remoteObject = fetchRemoteData(match.params.data);
    console.log("remoteObject = " + JSON.stringify(remoteObject));
    
    // .... rendering code
    // .... and other irrelevant stuffs to this question
}
```

If I run this code, on the console, I'm seeing the `remoteObject` is empty, but the `payload` inside the function `fetchRemoteData()` is not.

```
remoteObject = {}
payload = {"data":"some value"}
```

Now, let's say I have data stored in the browser (which is obviously I'm not supposed to do, but anyway) and if I fetch it using a generic function call, I'm not having problem.

```js
function fetchLocalData(name) {
    // read the data from a local js object
    // and return it
}

var RenderPlot = ({ match }) => {
    let remoteObject = fetchRemoteData(match.params.data);
    console.log("remoteObject = " + JSON.stringify(remoteObject));

    let localObject = fetchLocalData(match.params.data);
    console.log("localObject = " + JSON.stringify(lovalObject.m))
    
    // .... rendering code
    // .... and other irrelevant stuffs to this question
}
```

and the output --

```
localObject = 4
remoteObject = {}
payload = {"data":"some value"}
```

So, what's happening is the code gets the `localData` from `fetchLocalData()`, then calls `fetchRemoteData()` but it doesn't wait if the data is received or not. And then, keeps doing whatever in the rest of the code.

What I want is, the code should wait until the `remoteData` is received and then proceed to the next steps.

How do I do that?

Comment: fetchRemoteData returns a promise of data, not data itself. It’s asynchronous and needs another “await” or “then” to get it. “the code should wait until the remoteData is received and then proceed” - you can’t, that’s fundamental fact about React lifecycle. Since the component is functional, use useEffect hook.

Comment: Don't use `JSON.stringify` and you'll see that `remoteObject` is not an empty object but a promise

Comment: @Bergi I see, it's a promise.

Answer (score 2):

I can recommend you to store your received data in state of component like example below. If I understood you correctly -

```
const RenderPlot = ({ match }) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState()

  const fetchData = useCallback(async name => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch("/endpoint/" + name);   
      setData(response.data); // or whatever, depends on how you set your API up.
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e)
    }
  }, [])

  // in this case it works as componentDidMount;
  useEffect(() => {
    ;(async function() {
      await fetchData(match.params.data);
    })()
  }, [match.params])

  return (<div>...your jsx plot implementation</div>)
}
```

According to this flow you can compose two fetching,

```
  const fetch1 = useCallback(async () => {your first call api}, [])
  const fetch2 = useCallback(async () => {your second call api}, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    ;(async function() {
      await fetch1...
      await fetch2
    })()
  }, [match.params])
```

Or it can be like this

```
  const fetchData = useCallback(name => {
    try {
      const response1 = await fetch("/endpoint1/" + name);
      const response2 = await fetch("/endpoint2/" + name);

      // this line would be read after both of your responses come up. Here you can make some operation with both data.

      setData(response.data); // or whatever, depends on how you set your API up.
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e)
    }
  }, [])
```

Comment: Why not put everything in the `useEffect`? Makes error handling simpler.

Comment: yep, you are right, it depends on how you process data

Comment: but be sure, you can call two fetching in separate useEffect - then they would be called concurrently and in different time. you can call both of them inside one async useEffect - and second fetching will be waiting for first resonse,

Comment: That unnecessary wrapping in another function just makes it more complicated.

Comment: look, you cannot just call side effects in your functional component because of it cannot be performed correctly. In previous version of react you could call api(side effect) in componentDidMount method. In FC the proper way is to call it inside useEffect hook

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't need that `useCallback` at all, where you kinda duplicate the error handling and await syntax that should simply go in the `useEffect` hook.

Comment: thats true, nothing wrong with using useCallback anyway, but you can surely put this out of your component and call it the same way - it can keep your code cleaner tho

Comment: @wentris I'm getting `unexpected token error` at `async function()` under the brace `()`.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake and you had a correct point, I just did not see what you meant about extra unnecessary wrapper. check pls again or push your code to online editor and I will fix it

Comment: @wentris nope, it still doesn't work, if I do `console.log(data)` after `useEffect()`, it's says `undefined`.

Comment: @wentris yea it's working now, I had to do `await response.json();` inside `useCallback`. But during the compilation node says `React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'fetchData'. Either include it or remove the dependency array`, any idea?

Comment: it is not necessarily in this case. it is only warning to inform you that your hook useEffect will be using the first memoized version of fetchDat. But I am sure you can put fetchData in deps `useEffect(() => {fetchData()}, [fetchData])

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that ...return dataItem executes before that promise resolve the request. You need to use async await:

```
async function fetchRemoteData(name) {
   let dataItem = null;
   if (name) {
      const res = await fetch("/endpoint/" + name);
      dataItem = await res.json();
        
   } else {
        console.log("Error: No data for " + name);
   }
 return dataItem;
}
```

Comment: The returned `dataItem` is still a promise, I'm getting this: `remoteObject = [object Promise]`

Comment: Yes, that is because fetchRemoteData is an async function

Comment: You can get the value using then block or async await, fetchRemoteData(match.params.data).then(data => console.log("remoteObject = ",  data))

Comment: well, but I'm not going to do `console.log()` only, I need the data to plot. when I do `let remoteData = fetchRemoteData(match.params.data).then(data => {return data;})` the returned value is still `[object Promise]`.

Comment: You need to use the await var RenderPlot = async ({ match }) => {
    let remoteObject = await fetchRemoteData(match.params.data);